# Static objects for Web API 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, static-members

i have a web api 2 project the client will request some data that is in a xml format. That XML will never change and i am wondering how i could keep it in ram so that it doesnt deserialize the xml each time it needs data from that file.

Would deserializing it at launch and then keep it in a static variable be the best way as it will only be use for reading ?

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("api/dosomething")]
 public string DoSomething() {

     var myData = XmlSerializer(MyDataStruct).Deserialize(something);
     return myDate;
 }
```

Here the xml is only used to communicate values to clients. How can i make it so that i could deserialize it once and then return that directly. Would using static member enable this feature ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: How often is WebService class instanciated? How to make a persistent object in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117582/asp-net-how-often-is-webservice-class-instanciated-how-to-make-a-persistent-ob)

Comment: My thought would be to use the ASP.NET cache. Cache on first use, then pull from the cache after that.

Comment: Yes - static variable can be way to go. You an also use http cache. It depends on scenario - if it is being used frequently / you're not concerned about memory (or the size of xml is rather small) use static variable; if it is not being used frequently or memory consumption is concern - go with http cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cache-aside approach with a static field could be a fair option:

```
private static MyDataStruct _myData;

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/dosomething")]
public string DoSomething() {
    if(_myData == null)
    {
        _myData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDataStruct)).Deserialize(something);
    }

    return _myData;
}
```

If you want even better performance and completely skip both the deserialization from your XML and the serialization of your response body into JSON/XML, then I strongly suggest you an HTTP output caching approach, using a library like this one: [AspNetWebApi-OutputCache](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache).